# Add extension(*.xpi file) to firefox driver in Java using selenium when launched

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, firefox-addon

I went through a number of posts but none of them could help me get it working.

I would like to install my firefox addon using selenium and Java program i.e. have the addon installed when the firefox is launched.

Note: If I install my addon(*.xpi file) manually to the firefox browser by using opiton "Install Add-on from File.." option in settings, it installs correctly.

Java code:

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.addExtension(new File("my_webext.xpi"));        
        firefoxOptions.setProfile(profile);
        WebDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
        firefoxDriver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Selenium dependency version: (4.0.0-rc-1/4.0.0-alpha-2/3.141.59)

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Gecko Driver version: 0.24.0 or 0.29.1

Firefox version: 92.0(64-bit)

IDE: STS

OS: Windows 10

- When I run the above code, the Firefox borwser opens, but the addon is not installed.
- I see the following message on console:

```
    1631259829322   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\ab\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.CSQe58I2OCxk"
    1631259830585   Marionette  INFO    Marionette enabled
    JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.
    console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new NotFoundError("Could not open the file at C:\\Users\\ab\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.CSQe58I2OCxk\\search.json.mozlz4", (void 0)))
    1631259834207   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 59932
    1631259834612   RemoteAgent WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
    Sep 10, 2021 1:13:54 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
    INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first create a Firefox profile and then embed it to selenium code. You can use the default profile, but because of previous cashes and unnecessary addons, you'll maybe have 'Java Heap' error in first run. So the first step is:

***1. Creating new Firefox profile:***

1.1. Hold down the Windows Key and Press R on your keyboard and write `firefox.exe -p`

1.2. Click Create profile button on the opened windows and use wizard to create a new profile (In my case I created MyCreatedProfile)

[image]

Now select your new created profile and click on `Start Firefox` button

***2. Install addons:***

On Firefox window search the addons you want and install the addon, I searched for `discard-tab` and installed it. The installed addon is now on your created profile.

***3. Write code in selenium webDriver:***

This code should open Firefox with defined profile(Which the addons is installed on it)

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "c:/geckodriver.exe");

ProfilesIni profilesIni = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = profilesIni.getProfile("MyCreatedProfile");
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions= new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.setProfile(profile);
WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
try {
     driver.get("https://google.com/");
     Thread.sleep(60000);
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
     driver.quit();
 }
```

**4. Happily enjoy it :)**
[image]

Note that in this method you do not need to install each extension every time you create new Firefox driver. It helps specially when you need to have multiple extensions.

You can try the source code pushed in [Github](https://github.com/hanabizhani/SeleniumWebDriver-Tiny_projects/tree/main/AddBrowserExtension)

Comment: **Thanks. Tried, Didn't work.  Here is the code:**
`FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();`
`ProfilesIni profileIni = new ProfilesIni();`
`FirefoxProfile profile = profileIni.getProfile("MyProfileName");`
`profile.addExtension(new File("my_addon.xpi"));`
`firefoxOptions.setProfile(profile);`
`WebDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);`
`firefoxDriver.get("http://www.google.com");`

Comment: Also with the above code, i done see the warning on the console about: Could not open the file at <Path>/search.json.mozlz4

Comment: I tried to explain more in the answer. Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks @BzH. I am sorry, could you explain a little more pls? What version of selenium libs are you using as I see some difference in the APIs? What do you mean when you say "When you use this solution, you already have the extension permanently on the browser"? I aim to have my extension installed when the FF is launched programatically. Sorry for so many ques and confusion

Comment: I tried to write a code and test it... code worked fine for me ... check the edited answer, do step by step and not hesitate to ask any other questions if the problem exists. Good luck

Comment: Thanks, in the way you explained, you need to install the extension manually once. For me, I would like to launch Firefox as part of  a click on my desktop application and would like to have the firefox launched with the addon automatically(xpi file present in the installed directory). So Using code I would like to use the xpi to install and launch firefox programatically. A similar code for Chrome browser is able to do that i.e. able to programatically install chrome extension file when lauched(*.crx)